# Java clone item from one ArrayList into another?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to copy elements from one arrayList into another, I starting getting errors in my app and I think the problem is that I was doing shallow copies.

How can I add an item from one array into another doing a deep copy/clone?

This is how I was copying the elements up to now:

```
public ArrayList<ResolveInfo> myAppsArr = new ArrayList(); 
public ArrayList<ResolveInfo> allAppsArr = new ArrayList(); 

    myAppsArr.add(allAppsArr.get(0));
```

Comment: Yeah, that just copies references.

Comment: Are you nor sure? *'I think the problem is that I was doing shallow copies'*. You should be sure before starting to make deep copies.

Comment: You should use copy constructor of the ResolveInfo class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I add an item from one array into another doing a deep copy/clone?

ResolveInfo has a [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html#ResolveInfo%28android.content.pm.ResolveInfo%29) that creates new duplicate object for you:

```
myAppsArr.add(new ResolveInfo(allAppsArr.get(0)));
```

---

It appears this constructor was only added in API 17, you can *try* the generic clone method:

```
myAppsArr.add(allAppsArr.get(0).clone()); // No promises, I haven't tested this myself
```

Or you can create a method that manually creates a new ResolveInfo object since all of the member data is public.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most reliable way to do this for all android versions is to serialize ResolveInfo to parcel and create new ResolveInfo instance from that parcel.

```
ResolveInfo r1 = new ResolveInfo();
Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
r1.writeToParcel(p, 0);
ResolveInfo r2 = ResolveInfo.CREATOR.createFromParcel(p);
```